# Recommended way of invoking pg_repack on google cloud

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run, pg-repack

We have installed pg_repack on our postgresql database.

What is the best way to periodically invoke the `pg_repack` command using GCP infrastructure?

We tried running it using Cloud Run, but the 1 hour time limit often means that it times out before it can finish.

When it times out, we face the following error on subsequent runs:

```
WARNING: the table "public.<table name>" already has a trigger called "repack_trigger"
DETAIL: The trigger was probably installed during a previous attempt to run pg_repack on the table which was interrupted and for some reason failed to clean up the temporary objects. Please drop the trigger or drop and recreate the pg_repack extension altogether to remove all the temporary objects left over.
```

Which forces us to manually recreate the extension.

What is the easiest way to schedule pg_repack without the fear of it timing out? Alternatively, is there a way to gracefully shut down pg_repack, so that we can retry without having to recreate the extension?